# Fixing internal server error heroku/flask

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, flask, sqlalchemy

I have made my first heroku web app; it is a page with several links that redirect you to random pages just to test their ability to work.  All the pages work apart from the link that views all the entries created in my postgres database.  Every time I try to load that page I get an internal server error.

I have created my DATABASE_URL and set my PYTHONPATH all through my heroku cli through bash; and also set my procfile & wsgi file.  I have tried changing things around a little but it rather crashes the whole app rather than fixing my bug.

here is app.py file.

```
import os
import pyscopg2
from flask import Flask, render_template, g, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgres://fikwczdiymxhwf:73bf42c2c8a15fa59b77e93654b6383e1cf4f85bdf0156818d1cf39a77815f13@ec2-54-243-47-196.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d3uburco4fea1b'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

class Example(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "example"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    info = db.Column(db.String, )
    name = db.Column(db.String, )
    city = db.Column(db.String, )

   def __repr__(self):
       return '<Example {}>'.format(self.info)

DATABASE_URL = os.environ.get('postgres://fikwczdiymxhwf:73bf42c2c8a15fa59b77e93654b6383e1cf4f85bdf0156818d1cf39a77815f13@ec2-54-243-47-196.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d3uburco4fea1b')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/page_2')
def page_2():
    return render_template('random_page_2.html')

@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    return render_template('hello.html')

@app.route('/view_database')
def view_db():
    conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    data = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM example")
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    return render_template('view_database.html', data=data.fetchall())
```

main.py

```
import os
from app import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

wsgi.py
    from whitenoise import WhiteNoise

```
from app import app

application = WhiteNoise(app)
application.add_files('static/', prefix='static/')
```

These three files are are within one folder - along with the templates & static folder for pages, pictures stylesheet; this folder is labled flask-sqlalchemy-test-02.

Outside this folder there are the following files: procfile, requirements.txt, schema.sql, runtime

procfile:

```
web:gunicorn flask-sqlalchemy-test-02.wsgi:application --log-file=-
```

runtime:

```
pyhton-3.7.3
```

requirements.txt:

To obtain this, I went to my development folder in my command line directory and typed:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

I have been looking at other heroku deployed apps online and notice they have a gitignore file and some have an venv (environment folder).  I don't know if I have to include this in my app myself in order for this to work the way I intended.  I'm pretty sure its probably a missing / wrong line of code, but I really don't know where to look and would be very grateful if anybody could help!!

This is my major hurdle i need to get over in order to start making more interactive webpages.

web app:
https://flask-sqlalchemy-test-02.herokuapp.com/

my GitHub repository:
https://github.com/SinclairPythonAkoto/flask-sqlalchemy-test-02

you test the app yourself and check on the full details of my code.

many thanks! :)

Comment: What error are you getting specifically?

Comment: internal server error: The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Comment: I mean in your logs

Comment: psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory

Comment: (also) Is the server running locally and accepting
2019-08-06T14:03:08.581204+00:00 app[web.1]:  connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Comment: I've just tested my code and checked the logs which tells me there is a missing dsn and no parameters set.. what does this mean?